# Changing current frame without updating depsgraph

Tags: animation, interface, keyframes

Sometimes I set a keyframe and then start posing the next keyframe while forgetting to actually go to a new frame, so that when I realise my error my work is lost because on frame change everything snaps back to the last keyframe. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Thanks!

Repost from: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?350703-Changing-current-frame-without-updating-depsgraph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already modified things go ahead and create a new keyframe that overwrites the previous. Go to the dopesheet, select the newly created keyframe (by selecting the yellow diamond icon) and copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> a few times to undo the changes you had made in the pose and get your previous keyframe back. In the dopesheet move to a different frame and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) the modified keyframe, now you have both keyframes.

(But the easiest solution is to press the right arrow key so you are in a different frame before modifying anything...)